# Copy Data using AWS Powershell from Amazon S3 Server to local drive.

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, aws-powershell

I am trying Get-S3Object -BucketName pilot but it has lot of sub directories.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You probably want to use [Copy-S3Object](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Copy-S3Object.html) instead, for the actual copying.  Get-S3Object returns a collection of S3Object metadata.  Use Get-S3Object to isolate the objects you want to copy, and then pass the important information from them (the Key) into Copy-S3Object.

You can use the `KeyPrefix` Parameter to filter the results down to a specific sub-directory.  For example:

```
$srcBucketName = "myBucket"
$objects = get-s3object -bucketname $srcBucketName -KeyPrefix "mySubdirectory"
```

If you need to copy data from all of your directories, you can break this overall operation into smaller chunks by calling get-s3object individually, once for each directory in your bucket.

If the individual directories are still yet too large, you can further chunk your operation by using the `MaxKeys` parameter.

---

Once you're ready to copy, you can do something like this:

```
$objects | 
% { copy-s3object -BucketName $srcBucketName -Key $_.Key -LocalFile "somePath" }
```

...where you've defined your local path. You can even match the subdirectories and keys to your local path by resolving the key in a string: `"C:/someDir/$($_.Key)"`

- Get-S3Object Documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Get-S3Object.html
- Copy-S3Object Documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Copy-S3Object.html

Comment: I don't see a .BucketName on the objects returned from the first fetch. Checking the Documentation I don't see a Bucket properties on Amazon.S3.Model.S3Object.

Comment: @BozoJoe Thanks for the catch, that's absolutely correct.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use Read-S3Object to copy to your local job. Read-S3Object calls Get-S3Object, so you simply need this:

```
Read-S3Object -BucketName $myS3Bucket-KeyPrefix $myS3SubDirectory -Folder $myLocalFolder
```

Answer (score 1):

The version of AWS for Powershell that I have doesn't allow piping for `copy-s3object`. So you can use `read-s3object`.

Also, the `get-s3object` doesn't have a bucket name parameter, weird.

```
Get-S3Object -BucketName mybucket -Key path/to/files | % { Read-S3Object -BucketName mybucket -Key $_.Key -File $("C:\"+$_.key)}
```